# gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed (WSL Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, 20.04

after updating WSL Ubuntu i can't do `sudo apt-key add` with an error:

```
gpg: can't connect to the agent: IPC connect call failed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a [known bug in WSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3286). You can try adding the key manually using:

`curl -sL "http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=YOUR_KEY_HERE" | sudo apt-key add`

`YOUR_KEY_HERE` is the GPG key the package you need wants to install. An example would be: `0xA6A19B38D3D831EF`

Comment: That bug is for Ubuntu 18.04 WSL, but I never had such issues in 18.04. 20.04 is failing out of the box.

Comment: Thank you! It's also possible to copy a key to folder /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ manually

Comment: @DmitriyLyutov that's not recommended, as apt does not keep track of manually added keys. Use the package management utilities whenever you can to keep things maintainable!

Comment: This solution didn't work for me, but you can extract the keyid from this output: `curl -sL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg -vv --dry-run --import -`

Answer (score 9):

Uninstall the gpg that comes installed by default and install gnupg1 package instead

```
sudo apt remove gpg

sudo apt install gnupg1
```

Comment: That does the job. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me too.